# All apps are frozen, but login and sidebar works

Tags: unity, keyboard, mouse, xps

Recently, my 17.10 Ubuntu began ignoring all input (mouse clicks/keyboard/touch) on all of the open applications, but the side bar and top bar continue to work.  The login screen continues to work too (e.g. I can switch to text terminal and back).

So I can start a program by clicking its icon on the left side, or open preferences from the network lister at the top right, but I cannot do anything with them. All of keyboard and mouse events seem to vanish before making it to the app.

I use Dell XPS 13